# how to remove category word from category url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

hey maybe my question is possible or not but i want to remove category tag from wordpress category link
like that
my default category link is:  https://www.hindilovestory.in/category/sad-shayari/
but i want to make it like that:  https://www.hindilovestory.in/sad-shayari/
so i not want to show category tag inside url

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured from the WordPress Dashboard:

Go to Dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks >> Category base

You can clear the Category base field and leave it blank to have the desired result.